# Struggling to code in VB a simple population model

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to develop a population model in Visual Basics 2010.  However, I cant do the math nor the code!!  Suppose over 5 generations population growth of a fly look like this

```
GENERATION  JUVENILES  ADULTS  SENILES  TOTAL
0              10       10      10       30
1              20       10      10       40
2              20       20      10       50
3              40       20      20       80
4              40       40      20       100
5              80       40      40       160
```

In the model, Juvelines have a survival rate of 1 i.e. all juveniles survive into Adulthood. Adults have a survival rate of 1 also i.e. all adults survive into Seniles.  However, Seniles have a survival rate of 0 i.e. the current population all die.  Once completed, I will be able to vary the survival rates for each type of insect, but for now 1,1,0 works fine 
The second most important assumption here is that the birth rate of juveniles is double the current number of adults: 
New number of juveniles = Current number of adults * birth rate
My question is how do a represent this model as visual basic code?

This is all I have so far

```
'Assign Values of Textbox to Public Variables
BirthRate = txtBirthRate.Text
GenerationNum = txtGenerations.Text
PopulationJuveniles = txtPJ.Text
PopulationAdults = txtPA.Text
PopulationSeniles = txtPS.Text
SurvivalJuveniles = txtSJ.Text
SurvivalAdults = txtSA.Text
SurvivalSeniles = txtSS.Text

For Counter As Integer = 1 To GenerationNum
    'Calculate population of adults
    NewJuveniles = PopulationAdults * BirthRate
    NewAdults = PopulationJuveniles * SurvivalJuveniles 'the juveniles have matured 
    NewSeniles = PopulationAdults * SurvivalAdults 'the adults have aged
Next
```

Comment: You should always come stack overflow with code you've written and ask us to help fix it. Please don't come and ask us to write your code for you.

Comment: @Enigmativity apologies, the code I've done so far is a real non starter. I've only managed to create the forms, put default values in textboxes and assign the contents of these to variables. I understand that this query is a prime candidate to be marked down, but cant make any headway..grrr..

Comment: Ive been using the watch window to try and understand why the code I have is not happening, but not getting anywhere

Comment: At what rates do juveniles become adults and adults become seniles?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I want the rate to vary to experiment with the model.  However, in the scenario I give, Adults have a survival rate of 1 - meaning all survive into Seniles.  However, the current population of Seniles will all die as they have a survival rate of 0

Comment: So, at each step, the newJuveniles = popAdults * birthRate, newAdults = popJuveniles * survivalJuveniles (the juveniles have matured) and newSeniles = popAdults * survivalAdults (the adults have aged).

Comment: Can you give me ten to try and implement your suggestion? My Maths is awful?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes - I think the three formulas you give are correct.  Trying to wrap them into a For Loop but if I do this exactly as described, my results will only ever be 10 Juvenile, 10 Adult and 10 Senile

Comment: What are the values of `BirthRate` and `PopulationAdults` that you are reading from the TextBoxes? If your generation 1 has `NewJuveniles = BirthRate * PopulationAdults` then using your example values, `NewJuveniles` will be 2 * 10 = 20. Do you need to add `PopulationJuveniles = NewJuvelines`?

Comment: @Blackwood thanks for the response. The textbox BirthRate has 2 in it and PopulationAdults has 10 in it. You are correct, the first iteration of my for loop is 2*10=20.  However, I'm not sure how PopulationJuveniles = NewJuvelines will help me. Will have a fiddle with your suggestion

Comment: Well the problem seems to be that you have successfully calculated that in generation 1 `NewJuveniles` is 20, but you also say that number juveniles of juveniles is always 10. Why is that? I was guessing that the number you are displaying is `PopulationJuveniles` and you are never updating it. My guess might be wrong, how about if you post the code you have now so that we can see what is wrong about it.

Comment: @Blackwood I think you meant my reply to AndrewMorton was incorrect. Yes, you are right, given his code, I will get 20 Juvenile, 10 Adult and 10 Senile for all 5 iterations

Comment: @Blackwood I've updated the code as suggested by Andrew

Comment: I see that you have updated the code in your question (thank you). Do you see that every time round the loop you calculate the new number from the old ones (e.g. `NewJuveniles = PopulationAdults * BirthRate`) but you never change the old population numbers, so the result of the calculations will always be the same. One way to fix that is, at the end of the loop, change the old number to equal the new numbers (e.g. `PopulationJuveniles = NewJuvelines`).

Comment: @Blackwood - Ah I see - that's a good point - thanks.

Comment: @Blackwood Ahhhhh, that's it. You genius. Thank you. Please write up so I can credit your solution.

Comment: Once you have finished writing your code you should put `Option Explicit On` at the very top line of each page of your code. Then debug any errors. This will help make you a better coder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method calculates the population for each generation. Note that it includes code to validate the numbers entered in the TextBoxes (otherwise a bad number would cause an exception). It also displays the numbers for each generation in a ListBox.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Birthrate As Double, GenerationNum As Integer
    Dim PopulationJuveniles, PopulationAdults, PopulationSeniles As Double
    Dim SurvivalJuveniles, SurvivalAdults, SurvivalSeniles As Double
    Dim NewJuveniles, NewAdults, NewSeniles As Double

    If Not Double.TryParse(txtBirthRate.Text, Birthrate) _
      OrElse Integer.TryParse(txtGenerations.Text, GenerationNum) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter valid numbers for birthrate and generations")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not Double.TryParse(txtPJ.Text, PopulationJuveniles) _
      OrElse Double.TryParse(txtPA.Text, PopulationAdults) _
      OrElse Double.TryParse(txtPS.Text, PopulationSeniles) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter valid numbers for populations")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not Double.TryParse(txtSJ.Text, SurvivalJuveniles) _
      OrElse Double.TryParse(txtSA.Text, SurvivalAdults) _
      OrElse Double.TryParse(txtSS.Text, SurvivalSeniles) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter valid numbers for survival")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Counter As Integer = 1 To GenerationNum
        NewJuveniles = PopulationAdults * Birthrate
        NewAdults = PopulationJuveniles * SurvivalJuveniles 'the juveniles have matured 
        NewSeniles = PopulationAdults * SurvivalAdults 'Add + PopulationSeniles * SurvivalSeniles if SurvivalSeniles can ever be >0
        PopulationSeniles = NewSeniles
        PopulationAdults = NewAdults
        PopulationJuveniles = NewJuveniles
        ListBox1.Items.Add(PopulationJuveniles.ToString & ", " & PopulationAdults.ToString & ", " & PopulationSeniles.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```